# How to get data of users who created first data within a period of time?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the amount of money in all wallets for those who created their first wallets in the past 2 months?

I created an SQL fiddle to illustrate the tables. You are welcome to use this to see and run the SQL.
[My table schema and sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c02174)

The description of table schema and sample data is as below.

I have 2 tables. The first one is called `wallet`, with columns `wallet_id`, `wallet_owner_id`, `create_date`. We have many wallet owners, and each wallet owner can have multiple wallets. `create_date` indicates when the wallet was created. Both `wallet_id` and `wallet_owner_id` are unique.

e.g.

```
create table wallet(wallet_id int,wallet_owner_id varchar(20),create_date date);
insert into wallet values
(100000010,'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','2017-09-02'),
(100000034,'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','2018-06-02'),
(100000132,'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB','2017-05-03'),
(100001110,'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC','2018-05-02'),
(100000345,'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC','2018-05-06');
```

The second table is called `deposit`, with columns `wallet_owner_id`, `check_date`, `amount_in_all_wallets`. There is only one row for a `wallet owner` in a `ckeck date`

e.g.

```
create table deposit (amount_in_all_wallets int,wallet_owner_id varchar(20),check_date date);
insert into deposit values
(45,'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','2018-06-01'),
(89,'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB','2018-06-01'),
(97,'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC','2018-06-01'),
(11,'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC','2018-06-02');
```

Because AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA and BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB both created wallets before the past 2 months, I the results should be

```
amount_in_all_wallets|wallet_owner_id|check_date|first_create_date
97                   |CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC|2018-06-01|2018-05-02
11                   |CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC|2018-06-02|2018-05-02
```

Query :

```
SELECT d.amount_in_all_wallets, d.wallet_owner_id, d.check_date, min(d.create_date) as first_create_date
FROM deposit d 
JOIN wallet w ON d.wallet_owner_id = w.wallet_owner_id
WHERE w.create_date > '2018-05-01'
```

This is not working because I couldn't find a way to incorporate the idea of "created their first wallets in the past 2 months". How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could add another condition for `INNER JOIN` that checks for desired dates:

```
SELECT amount_in_all_wallets,
       w.wallet_owner_id,
       check_date,
       MIN(w.create_date) AS first_create_date
FROM wallet w
JOIN deposit d ON w.wallet_owner_id = d.wallet_owner_id
    AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) <=
        (SELECT MIN(create_date)
            FROM wallet
            WHERE wallet_owner_id = w.wallet_owner_id)
GROUP BY amount_in_all_wallets,
         w.wallet_owner_id,
         check_date
```

Comment: This is not working because you include owner AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, meaning have a row `45|AAAAAAAAAAAAAA|2018-06-01|2018-06-02` His first wallet was not created within the past 2 months, so this row shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
select *
from deposit d join (
    select wallet_owner_id, min(create_date) create_date from wallet
    group by wallet_owner_id
    having min(create_date) >= date_add(now(), interval -2 month)  
) w on w.wallet_owner_id = d.wallet_owner_id;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The row `45|AAAAAAAAAAAAAA|2018-06-01|2018-06-02` shouldn't exist in the result. AAAAAAAAAAAAAA's first wallet was not created within the past 2 months, so I need to exclude the data of AAAAAAAAAAAAAA.

Comment: What I need in the result is the first_create_date, not the create_date. In your join, it will generate multiple rows for a single create_date, so even the create_date of 2018-05-06 has a record.